# Is the leading eigenvalue always the first in Eigensystem[M][[1]]?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Although it has been the case in all the instances I've tried yet I wasn't able to explicitly make sure this is the rule (I looked though official documentation and this forum before asking of course), i.e. that when calculating the Eigensystem[] of a matrix, the eigenvalues are given in an order by decreasing magnitude. Is this the case by design as I suspect so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, consult the documentation. Always look under "Details" or "Details and Options". These kinds of questions should be answered there. In this case,

> If they are numeric, eigenvalues are sorted in order of decreasing absolute value.

If they are not numerical, e.g. if your matrix contains a symbol, then this is no longer true.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the Detalis and Options part. My bad.

Comment: @BenjaminMárkus For the future, consider that section the most important part (after the basic syntax).

Comment: Shouldn't this be closed then?

Comment: @Feyre I would prefer it to be closed as a duplicate. I that is not possible (there's no existing open question), it can serve as a duplicate for other questions in the future. While this is "easily found in the documentation", it seems to be a reasonable question that comes up frequently, and that people will certainly google for.